# What are '\e[s' and '\e[u' character sequences?

Tags: bash, terminal, ansi-escape

In GNU codes I have seen `\e[s` and `\e[u` character sequences.What do they mean?
How does it help moving the cursor on console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape character sequences `\e[s` and `\e[u` usually refer to printable forms of the save/restore cursor (position) control sequences.  Those date back (at least) to [`ansi.sys`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-ansi_sys-old) from MS-DOS.  Several terminal types (including [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)) support these control sequences.

The `\e` stands for the ASCII *escape* character.  In termcap or [terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html), this would be an uppercase `\E` (still, the same code 27).

Some implementations of `echo` (whether separate executable or built-in shell command) interpret `\e` as the escape character.  Depending on *version*, you may see this supported in GNU coreutils `echo` or `bash` (which can be and are used on a variety of platforms, including Windows).  The relevant standard for [`echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) uses `\033`.  The `\e` was likely chosen lowercase for consistency with the *standard* escapes such as `\n` and `\t`.